# Where to apply silicone to this shower screen?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, sealant, silicone

I am having difficulty interpreting these installation instructions for a shower screen. Where should I be applying silicone? To the horizontal joint outside the shower and to the vertical joints inside?
[image]

Comment: Usually you seal from where the water comes from(inside the shower).  Is there something different on the bottom that is not shown, maybe drain holes on the inside?

Comment: That's not outside & inside, it's left- & right-handed door mount, from the inside.

Comment: @Tetsujin   The diagram does make it look like the bottom gun is on the other side.  They even change colour/don't show the caulking as being on the same side.

Comment: That sounds right--the inside of the bottom should usually not be caulked. Be sure to heed the warning against 24-hour showers. That's too long of a shower.

Comment: @crip659 - I'd just call it a bad drawing. they didn't bother masking the gun image, or finishing the red line. tbh, you just gun every bit that could leak, except the sliding door. It doesn't really need a drawing. ;)